# issue get value from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a problem with extract and change value in NSDictionary.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"dictRecensiti"];
NSLog(@"dict %@",dict);
```

this is the output:

```
dict (
    (
        {
        ingredientiRecensito = "AQUA,CETYL%20PALMITATE,PROPYLENE%20GLYCOL,SORBITOL,PRUNUS%20DULCIS,ISODODECANE,STEARIC%20ACID,CETYL%20ALCOHOL,LANOLIN,CYCLOPENTASILOXANE,CALENDULA%20OFFICINALIS,SQUALANE,HEXYLENE%20GLYCOL,FRUCTOSE,GLUCOSE,SUCROSE,UREA,DEXTRIN,ALANINE,GLUTAMIC%20ACID,ASPARTIC%20ACID,HEXYL%20NICOTINATE,TRIETHANOLAMINE,OCTYL%20METHOXYCINNAMATE,OCTYL%20COCOATE,BISABOLOL,CARBOMER,PHENOXYETHANOL,METHYLPARABEN,BUTYLPARABEN,ETHYLPARABEN,PROPYLPARABEN,SEBACIC%20ACID,CI%2047000,CI%2061565,GLYCERYL%20LINOLEATE,GLYCERYL%20LINOLENATE,BUTYLENE%20GLYCOL,ENTEROMORPHA%20COMPRESSA%20EXTRACT,ALLANTOIN,SODIUM%20METHYLPARABEN,SODIUM%20BUTYLPARABEN,SODIUM%20ETHYLPARABEN,SODIUM%20PROPYLPARABEN,HYALURONIC%20ACID,BHT,PARFUM";
        nomeRecensito = "Levissime%20Crema%20idratante%20pelli%20sensibili";
        testoRecensito = "Massimomosmaomomaodmosmodmasoosaocaoaomcoasocmosamomaodm.%20Dmosadmoasmdomasd.%20Sdoamdoamodsmao";
        tipoRecensito = "Crema%20viso%20pelli%20Sensibili";
        }
    ),
        {
        ingredientiRecensito = "WATER,GLYCERIN,PEG-7%20GLYCERYL%20COCOATE,DISODIUM%20LAURETH%20SULFOSUCCINATE,SODIUM%20COCOAMPHOACETATE,PEG-25%20HYDROGENATED%20CASTOR%20OIL,CETEARETH-60%20MYRISTYL%20GLYCOL,PEG-200%20HYDROGENATED%20GLYCERYL%20PALMATE,LAURETH-3,COCO-GLUCOSIDE,AQUAPHILUS%20DOLOMIAE%20EXTRACT,ARGININE,CAPRYLYL%20GLYCOL,CITRIC%20ACID,EVENING%20PRIMROSE%20OIL/PALM%20OIL%20AMINOPROPANEDIOL%20ESTERS,GLYCINE,OENOTHERA%20BIENNIS%20OIL,SORBIC%20ACID,TOCOPHEROL";
        nomeRecensito = "Avene%20XeraCalm%20A.D.%20olio%20detergente%20liporestitutivo";
        testoRecensito = Blblblbnnn;
        tipoRecensito = "Olio%20detergente";
        }
    )
```

now i want replace %20 and so i wrote:

```
 NSString *stringV = [dict valueForKey:@"ingredientiRecensito"];
stringV = [stringV stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];
NSLog(@"%@",stringV);
```

the app crashes and this is output:

```
[__NSArrayI stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc90f360
```

thanks in advance

EDIT: **I understand that this is not the best solution to take this nsuserdefault, and so I'm trying to radically change the code to have another type of output from this nsuserdefault. thanks at all**

Comment: I suggest studying the description of that object more carefully. It is not a dictionary but an array.

Comment: Also read the documentation of `- [NSArray valueForKey:]`.

Comment: @H2CO3 so I suggest not to use a NSDictionary for nsuserdefault but get a NSMutableArray?

Comment: No. You use whatever data structure you want/find useful. You just have to call the appropriate methods on it. For that, you'll need to read its documentation.

Answer (score 3):

It seems also that you're trying to access the valueForKey for an array, not of a dictionary, as there are multiple objects in dict. That's why you get that error involving NSArray.

If you wish to replace values for that key inside every object iterate over the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [dict count]; i++) {
    NSString *stringV = [dict[i] valueForKey:@"ingredientiRecensito"];
    stringV = [stringV stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];
    NSLog(@"%@",stringV);
}
```

I would also change the name of dict to something less confusing, as this is an array containing two dictionaries.

If I may add, If this is part of an app I would definitely refactor the code, if this is just a script to print out information I think Objective-C is probably not the best language around to do this kind of operation.

Comment: sorry but on dict[i] give me error: expected method to read array element not found on object of type NSDictionary *'

Comment: Mmmm, it's not clear from the print if the object is an NSArray containing NSDictionary(s). The easiest way to deal with this is to put a breakpoint on the NSLog(@"dict %@",dict); line and inspect the object in XCode during runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Check out :

```
  for (NSDictionary *ingredient in dict){
         NSString *content = [ingredient objectForKey:@"ingredientiRecensito"];
         content = [content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];                       
         NSLog(@"ingredient: %@", content);
  }
```

Comment: app crash with: [__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbca3710

Comment: See ,, If you are about to use NSArray then you need to use "valuForKey" Or "objectForKey" for NSDictionary.. If Dict also NSDictionary and ingredient also Dictionary , So then how you are geting this exception..

Comment: i'm try to change [ingredient valueForKey:@"ingredientiRecensito"] and i had this output [__NSArrayI stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbcb9190

Comment: Ok .. first check whether **dict** is valid one .

Comment: and first check whether **NSLog(@"Content Before Appending %@",content);**  Before **stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString**

Comment: before appending print this:  (
    "AQUA,CETYL%20PALMITATE,PROPYLENE%20GLYCOL,SORBITOL,PRUNUS%20DULCIS,ISODODECANE,STEARIC%20ACID,CETYL%20ALCO . . ."
)  and after crash

Comment: If you are getting this means , You have a string then there is no way of through exception with **stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString** .  Better put breakpoint and check'